# Finding loop invariant of Lowest common multiple function

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, correctness-proof

So I have the following function:

```
def lcm(a,b):
    x = a
    y = b
    while x != y:
        if x < y:
            x += a
        else:
           y += b
    return x
```

I'm not sure how I will go about finding the loop invariant of this question. I know I have to find some sort of relationship between $x$ and $y$ but nothing seems to hold or is helpful in actually proving correctness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, a possible loop invariant is "$x$ is a multiple of $a$ and $y$ is a multiple of $b$".

Then this *almost* proves partial correctness, because we know that after the loop terminates $\neg(x \neq y) \to x = y$, thus $x$ must be a multiple of both $a$ and $b$.

What this loop invariant *doesn't* show is that $x$ is the smallest possible such number.

To solve this, we must complicate our loop invariant:

1. If $x \geq y$, $x$ is the smallest multiple of $a$ that is bigger than or equal to $y$.
2. If $y \geq x$, $y$ is the smallest multiple of $b$ that is bigger than or equal to $x$.

Now it's up to you to prove that this invariant is correct.